# Correct term for "solo investigator" in a research

Tags: research, terminology

I'm looking for a phrase that describes a condition where one and only one person is doing academic research, from proposal to paper report - as opposed to the work being done in a team. The phrase "solo investigator" comes to my mind, but I don't think it is a formal term yet.

> To attack this quantum physics problem, John is appointed as the *team leader* in a  research group in Cambridge. Bob is one of the *team members*.
>
> Their friend Adam is a *solo investigator* (?) tackling a similar problem in Boston.

Comment: Is it really that important to emphasize that someone is working alone?

Comment: On an unrelated note, "tackle" is a better substitute for "attack" a problem.

Comment: I would say "their *acquaintance* Adam is *independently* engaging with a similar problem in Boston".

Comment: I think that this question cannot be answered unless we understand *why* it matters whether somebody is working alone.  Few researchers are ever truly isolated...

Comment: @StephanKolassa - Not sure about that, seems to me that while this is about English language the terminology is specific to academia. However, that's a lot of close votes... we can move if everyone thinks that's the right approach.

Comment: @Moriarty *researching independently* will most likely be construed as not sharing data until the work is completed by all parties; not necessarily *working alone*.

Comment: _lone ranger_ (figuratively)

Comment: *lone researcher* has a certain ring to it.

Answer (score 1):

> *Working alone*, their friend Adam is *researching* a similar problem in Boston.

Comment: *Flying solo out in Boston* sounds nice, too. Now I'm stuck trying to think of a single word for *working alone*.